# Spring MVC: how to prevent Spring from adding commas in numbers for generated strings

Tags: spring-mvc

On my JSP page, I have the following:

```
<spring:message code="label.generate.codes" arguments="${requestScope.numberOfCodes}"/>
```

In my properties file, I have the following message:

```
label.generate.codes=generate {0} codes.
```

If the numberOfCodes is 1000 or more, here is the final generated string in html:

```
generate 1,000 codes.
```

How can I prevent Spring from adding commas in a number? Put it another way, I want to have the  following:

```
generate 1000 codes.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
label.generate.codes=generate {0,number,#} codes.
```

Or you could pass a String instead of a number as argument to the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think spring message tag adds the comma, you mentioned. It may have been
 introduced due to toString() implementation of your numberOfCodes object.